# Change in the hostname/user in Terminal in Leopard OSX

Tags: macos, terminal

My terminal previously showed `subalcharla$` at the command line.

The terminial is now showing `subalcharla@subal-charlas-macbook ~ $`.

How do I go back to the original setting?

What is the difference between the two?

How did this get changed without my doing so?

Answer (score 2):

At the end of `~/.profile` add the line

```
export PS1='\u$ '
```

to get your old prompt back.

To do this you can type

```
 nano ~/.profile
```

which will bring up a text editor. Press down until you get to the bottom of the file. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create a new line, and paste in

```
export PS1='\u$ '
```

Press <kbd>Control+X</kbd> to exit the editor and say "yes" when asked if you want to save. Now restart your terminal and your prompt should be restored.

The first prompt you gave shows your username, the second shows your username and hostname. There is no error and the functionality of your bash shell is *not* changed by changing the prompt.

Something must have changed your `PS1` environment variable, maybe a system update or the installation of software. It's probably benign though.

Comment: Hey Jon, I am really new at this could you please write down for me what I am supposed to at subalcharla@subal-charlas-macbook ~ $. How do I get to the file ~/ .profile and where do I put PS1='\u$    Thanks a ton!

Comment: # MacPorts Installer addition on 2010-05-01: adding an appropriate $export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH # Finished adapting your PATH environ variable for use with MacPorts.#MacPorts Installer addition on 2010-05-01: adding an appropriate $export MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH
# Finished adapting your MANPATH environment variable for use with MacPorts# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.5# The orginal version is saved in .profile.pysave PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

Comment: The above code showed up after I entered "nano ~/ .profile" in the terminal, and the text editor did not open up. To counter this, I entered "mate nano ~/ .profile" and added "export PS1='\u$" at the bottom of the screen in the text editor and saved the file. But the terminal still shows "subalcharla@subal-charlas-macbook ~ $" at the beginning of the command line.

Comment: I typed in "echo PS1" and got \u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $. I think I seem to be working on some sort of branch of a git instead of the master. Any suggestions of getting out of the branch?

Comment: 1. The text editor (called "nano") is what was displaying the code. You need to add the line "export PS1='\u$ '" to the end of that code. However, since you can access your editor called "mate", you can probably use "mate ~/.profile" to edit the file instead of nano. 2. You probably wound up adding the line to a new file called "nano", which would not give you back your prompt. You can do a "ls nano" to verify this.

Comment: Nope, you're not in a git branch, that code just displays the name of the git branch you're in, in your prompt, WHEN you're in one.

Comment: Your prompt would probably look something like this: subalcharla@subal-charlas-macbook ~ somegitbranch $

Comment: Just as some background information, I had tried the terminal to show the name of the branch I was working and also to display the branch in a different color from the master branch's color by using this command PS1="$RED\$(date +%H:%M) \w$YELLOW \$(parse_git_branch)$GREEN\$ ". Do you think this would have caused the PS1 environment variable to change?

Comment: Oops! I had no clue that nano is the name of a text editor. Anyway, I typed "mate ~/ .profile" and saved the file with "export PS1 = '\u$'", but there's no change in the terminal. FYI: My ruby, rails settings have gone back to the old settings, i.e. 1.8.6 and 1.3.2 and rvm does not exist. I quite sure my working directory (\w) has got switched to parse_git_branch during the color and branch name change. Otherwise why would rvm suddenly disappear and ruby and rails downgrade their versions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it got changed, but it's controlled by some symbol definitions.  Use "man bash" in the terminal and search for the section called "PROMPTING".  There are symbols named PS1-to-4 that it uses to construct the prompt.

Comment: I typed in "echo PS1" and got \u@\h \W[\033[32m]$(parse_git_branch)[\033[00m] $. I think I seem to be working on some sort of branch of a git instead of the master. Any suggestions of getting out of the branch?

Comment: Just as some background information, I had tried the terminal to show the name of the branch I was working and also to display the branch in a different color from the master branch's color by using this command PS1="$RED\$(date +%H:%M) \w$YELLOW \$(parse_git_branch)$GREEN\$ ". Do you think this would have caused the PS1 environment variable to change?